# Converting in-memory sqlite database to char array

Tags: database, sqlite

I have an in-memory sqlite database which I want to convert to a char array, to write it on a flash memory. I have googled and I found this solution:  [Loading and Saving In-Memory Databases](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). As I am using sqlite on a new hardware (`SQLITE_OS_OTHER=1`), a new VFS is needed, but the problem is; since there is no file system on my hardware (i.e. open file), the only way left is converting in-memory sqlite to char*.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory databases are not associated with a file. To get access to such a database's data, you would have to [define your own page cache implementation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/pcache_methods2.html).

However, it would be easier to write a VFS that treats the flash as one large file (or two files, if you need a rollback journal).